# Как задать элементу стиль при наведении?

Tags: css

Вот документ:

```
<div class="rate_num">...</div>
<div class="rate">...</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на класс rate у класса rate_num появилась граница?

Сделал типа такого:

```
.rate a:hover  .rate_num {
  border: 1px solid #ADBCCB;
}
```

или

```
.rate a:hover ~ .rate_num {
 border: 1px solid #ADBCCB;
}
```

Но оба варианта не работают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:hover
Будет работать только в том случае, если элемент у которого будет появляться граница будет находится внутри элемента на который вы наводите.

Если вы используете чистый css, то нужно переделать разметку так:

```
<div class="rate">
   <div class="rate_num">...</div>
...
</div>
```

тогда будет работать запись

```
.rate:hover .rate_num {
  border: 1px solid #ADBCCB;
}
```

Если в проекте используется jQuery сделать так http://jsfiddle.net/Vafqr/

```
$('.rate').hover(
    function(){
        $('.rate_num').css("border", "1px solid #ADBCCB" );
    },
    function(){
        $('.rate_num').css("border", "none" );           
    }
);
```

Comment: Спасибо, поправил html css